# autofac's Func<T> to resolve named service

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, autofac

Given registered services:

```
builder.RegisterType<Foo1>().Named<IFoo>("one").As<IFoo>();
builder.RegisterType<Foo2>().Named<IFoo>("two").As<IFoo>();
builder.RegisterType<Foo3>().Named<IFoo>("three").As<IFoo>();
```

Can I retrieve named implementations of `IFoo` interface by injecting something like `Func<string, IFoo>` ?

```
public class SomeClass(Func<string, IFoo> foo) {
    var f = foo("one");
    Debug.Assert(f is Foo1);

    var g = foo("two");
    Debug.Assert(g is Foo2);

    var h = foo("three");
    Debug.Assert(h is Foo3);
}
```

I know I can do it with `Meta<>`, but I don't want to use it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could register your own resolving delegate like this:

```
builder.Register<Func<string, IFoo>>(c =>
    {
        var cc = c.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
        return named => cc.ResolveNamed<IFoo>(named);
    });
```

Comment: Minor edit - the 'c' parameter is a temporary; you need to resolve IComponentContext if you want to hang onto it like this.

c => { var cc = c.Resolve<IComponentContext>(); return named => cc.Resolve<IFoo>(named); }

Comment: Agreed - I'd like to find a way to make this easier to catch.

Comment: Why are you resolving the IComponentContext ? The parameter c is already IComponentContext. You can use it like this :builder.Register<Func<string, object>>(c => named => c.Resolve<object>(named));

Comment: @user137348 - as Nicholas mentions, the 'c' context is a temporary context instance. If you "store" that context in the lambda we're registering the lambda will not work as expected. By resolving 'IComponentContext' we'll get a "real" context that can be passed around.

Comment: Still one typo, should be c => { var cc = c.Resolve<IComponentContext>(); return named => cc.ResolveNamed<IFoo>(named); }

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev - you're right, don't know why I changed that to object :|

Comment: @PeterLillevold thanks. you're right. removed comment to avoid confusion.

Comment: @JJS -  all's well. I'll remove my comments on this too, then :)